# Yii 1.15 ORM - too many SHOW statements

Tags: mysql, optimization, yii

Yii's ORM uses too many SHOW table statements.

It looks so in logs:

[image]

PhpMyadmin's stats  says that SHOW statements take about 46% resources of MySql:

[image]

Is there any way to mitigate this?

**EDIT**

I forgot to add that I have caching enabled like the following:

schemaCachingDuration => 7200

As I understand it should cache table schema for 2 hours. But it's updated anyway.

Comment: (1) Complain to the ORM provider.  (2) Don't use an ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the schemaCachingDuration (at least in your live system)

[schemaCachingDuration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#schemaCachingDuration-detail)

- is this on your development version?
  Could be that if define('YII_DEBUG', true); it isn't cached.
- have you enabled 'cache' as well ? [final deployment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/final.deployment)

You also have to set the `cache`setting:
e.g.

```
'cache'=>array(
        //'class'=>'CApcCache',
        //'class'=>'CDummyCache',
        'class'=>'CDbCache',
),
```

Comment: right, you were pointing the proper direction. I found the solution here - http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26753-schema-caching-does-not-work/  . The problem was that I used APC caching . Using Cfilecache solved the issue

Comment: you can also leave the apc chaching for the web content and use a different (additional) cache for the db meta queries.  you can set the db used cache with this.
`'schemaCacheID' => 'DBcache',` and have a DBcache setting which uses `CFileCache`  or `CDbCache`   where you can also set the `'connectionID'=>'db'`. Haven't tested it (because i don't use apc)  but it should be possible.